# Import multiple csv into R using a For loop

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, import

Hi I am new to R and struggling to understand where my script is going wrong. I am trying to import only the csv files that fall between the 2 dates **Sdate** 
 & **Fdate** entered near the top of the script. The script runs fine without any errors but only pulls in the last file in the list. I am on windows 10 and all the files are on the local machine. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
Sdate <- as.Date("2018-10-01")
Fdate <- as.Date("2018-10-30")
Ndate = as.character.Date(seq.Date(from = as.Date(Sdate), to = as.Date(Fdate), 
                                   by = "days"), format ="%Y%m%d")

for (i in Ndate){
  MyData <- read.csv(
    file=paste('D:/Data/Merlin Data/Merlin BDD/T1/BDD_',i,'_T1.csv',sep = ""), 
    header=TRUE, sep=",")
}
```

Comment: The problem you're experiencing is due to the fact that you're overwriting MyData with every subsequent iteration in the for loop. Perhaps you meant to do something with it (append to an existing dataframe? process and save?) while _in_ the for loop?

Comment: you could use `mydata <- c(mydata, read.csv*)`  your are just overwriting your `mydata` everytime, so try to append instead

Comment: @12b345b6b78 So if I imported into a temporary table and then append the data to MyData would that work.

Comment: @mischva11 would that pull in all the files in the folder. There are a lot of files in there I don’t need.

Comment: aw, sorry. No i was just to lazy to write the whole read.csv function. Use it like you did if you get all your files through this. The star was meant like "the rest of the function".

Comment: Like you already said. I would create a new dataframe `MyData` with shape of your Data and then append your files with `c(MyData, read.csv(file=paste('D:/Data/Merlin Data/Merlin BDD/T1/BDD_',i,'_T1.csv',sep = ""), header=TRUE, sep=","))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are overwriting your variable everytime your loop. So let's change that. You need to append your files to your dataframe.

One solution is to create an initial dataframe

`MyData <- read.csv(file='D:/Data/Merlin Data/Merlin BDD/T1/BDD_20181001_T1.csv', header=TRUE, sep=",")`

and afterwards append your data to this one with concatenation`c()`. Since you already read the first file let's set `Sdate` to `Sdate<-as.Date("2018-10-02")`
You should be able to read your Data then with:

`for (i in :Ndate){
  MyData <- read.csv(file=paste('D:/Data/Merlin Data/Merlin BDD/T1/BDD_',i,'_T1.csv',sep = ""), header=TRUE, sep=",")
}`